# Spark + scala new pipline for StringIndexer multiple columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I try to apply `StringIndexer()` on multiple columns, I work with **Scala** and **Spark** 2.3.
This is my code:

```
val df1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("file:///c:/tmp/spark-warehouse/train.csv")

val feat = df1.columns.filterNot(_ .contains("BsmtFinSF1"))

val inds = feat.map { colName =>
  val indexer1 = new StringIndexer()
    .setInputCol(colName)
    .setOutputCol(colName + "I")
    .fit(df1)

  Array(indexer1)
}

val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(inds.toArray)
```

But, I have this error:

> Error:(134, 50) type mismatch;
>
> found   : Array[Array[org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel]]
>   required: Array[? <: org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage]
>
> Note: Array[org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel] >: ? <: org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage, but class Array is invariant in type T.
>   You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >: ? <: org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage`. (SLS 3.2.10)
>      val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(inds.toArray)

Any help will be appreciated.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.setStages` takes an `Array[PipelineStage]`, but actually it becomes `Array[Array[PipelineStage]` because you wrap `indexer1` into redundant Array here: `Array(indexer1)`. Map function returns a collection of the same type. Elements of this collection are resulted by an application of a function passed to Map. So just try like this:

```
val inds = feat.map { colName =>
   new StringIndexer()
    .setInputCol(colName)
    .setOutputCol(colName + "I")
    .fit(df1)          
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help,  please there is a way  to not apply a StringIndexer  on the columns with intiger  type ? Thank you

Comment: you are welcome. I think this would separate question. I do not know how `StringIndexer` is used, but based on the types, one can set a `DataFrame` directly to `pipeline` like : `val pipeline = new Pipeline().fit(df1)`

Comment: how to deal with OneHotEncoderEstimator I am unable to fit columns